# Random convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, random

I am collaborating with a couple of machine learning specialists on a project related to phase retrieval.  The problem we are investigating has solutions which are convex 2D functions on a rectangular domain $[0,n]\times [0,m]$.  They have asked me to provide them with a selection of such convex functions for use in training their model.

**Question: Are there any natural ways to generate random 2D convex functions on a rectangle $[0,n]\times [0,m]$?**

This is of course an open ended question.  I can conceive several ways to generate random convex functions (e.g. taking the max of random linear functions), but nothing seems particularly natural.

Comment: This is an interesting question (+1). I know that maximising some random linear functions is only an initial thought, but doing so will generate only polyhedral functions (without care, a lot of them with few faces on the rectangle). Does it matter if this neural net only trains on a small class of convex functions? Though I suppose this will be true no matter how we generate them. Would it matter, say, if all the functions were differentiable? It might help to glimpse a little into what this training data might be used for.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think having all the functions be differentiable would be probably preferable, in fact.  To be honest, I'm not sure what the ML algorithms need, but I can tell you that the space of convex functions relevant to this problem is roughly the set of solutions to the Monge-Ampere PDE, if that means anything to you.  Such functions are generally piecewise smooth.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning: In 1D there is a simple way to generate a random convex function.  You just generate a random nonnegative number at each point in your domain, corresponding to the second derivative of the desired function, and integrate twice.  This doesn't work in 2D, because a randomly generated field of symmetric matrices (a candidate Hessian) is generally not the second derivative of some scalar function.

Comment: I won't lie, my mind was heading in a direction like this. I was wondering, perhaps, if there was a way to generate the first derivative: a cyclic maximally monotone operator. If you drop the "cyclic", something might be possible through resolvents and Minty's theorem; if we could generate a random non-expansive map $P$, then $\frac{I + P}{2}$ is firmly non-expansive, and its inverse would be maximally monotone. All maximally monotone maps can be generated in this way. However, if it's not cyclicly maximally monotone, then it won't be the derivative of a convex function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that the summation of convex functions is convex, you could just sample $N$ random points $x_i$ in $[0,n]\times [0,m]$ and then associate each of them with a curvature $\alpha \sim \cal {U}[0,1]$, and get :

$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i (x-x_i)^2
$$

You can sample other $\alpha$s, but you get my point.

This is differentiable, easy to obtain, and you can say things about the function given that you know the distributions.

Comment: This can only generate quadratic functions, and by the central limit theorem the coefficients will be normally distributed for large $N$.  So if one was to limit themselves to this form of function, you might be better off just randomly generating the coefficients of a single quadratic polynomial.